# Can I move/copy emails from Gmail to Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I want to share some of my emails with my colleagues. I thought it could be done via Google Docs. It would be also kind of backup if this could be done.

We are on Google Apps.

**Can I automatically copy an email with attachment(s) to Google Docs?**

Answer (score 2):

There's a Zap for that. Try creating new [Google Docs from Gmail emails](https://zapier.com/z/CJb/zapbook/gmail/google-docs/1974/create-google-docs-entry-from-gmail/). Set it so that when you label your emails with a certain label it fires the Zap and creates a new document in Google Docs. Once it's in Google Docs you can set sharing permissions so colleagues can see it.

Check the [Gmail to Drive Zaps](https://zapier.com/z/CEU/zapbook/gmail/google-drive/) to snag attachments.

[image: Gmail -> GDocs]

Disclosure: I do run Zapier, but even if I didn't this would still be the solution I use. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a GMail Labs feature called "Create a Document" but it seems to be not compatible with the latest version of GMail. I have it enabled and judging by the description & my memory the button should've been next to `Print` and `New window` but it's not there.

**Update**
The command is now located in the `More` menu.

Comment: I need this to be done automatically. Preferably based on the label.

Comment: @Radek then you need custom solutions.

Comment: @dnbrv Check under the more menu - http://i.imgur.com/vfaWW.png

Comment: Can I code the custom solution?

Comment: I wasn't able to have the "create a document" bring over the attachment. That probably isn't surprising because many attachments would look bad as html or text.

Comment: @Radek: There's no automatic function in GMail that can be performed based on a label because that requires the system to scan for label changes.

Comment: @Bibhas: Thanks! Indeed, it's now in the *More* menu.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: Why would you expect the attachment to be brought over with the body of the email *into a document*? The two can't be merged in any logical way.

Comment: @dnbrv: The OP had that as a requirement.

Comment: @dnbrv: It would be a repository of test results that I receive via email. The summary is received by everybody but I want to share the details & attachments.

Comment: why not making a filter that fowards automatically all the emails that you want to share with your colleagues?

Comment: @dnbrv Gmail Labs "Create a Document" has been removed from Labs and is now only available via Google Chrome: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/gmail-labs-suggest-a-labs-feature/documents/gmail-labs-suggest-a-labs-feature/Cn6-S4v-OLc/o5YPKttJqfgJ

Answer (score 1):

Theres also an application called CutePDF. This application wil install a printer (called cutepdf) and everything that you print with this printer will be converted to a pdf document.

With this application you can print the mail from gmail to this CutePDF printer and the mail will become a PDF document. After that, you can of course upload this PDF document to google docs again.

Comment: perfect - you can also use PDFCreator

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with Google scripts. Here's one which accepts a Gmail label and will archive mails from that label to your Google Drive. Please note that this is not a backup. Emails will be moved to Google drive (only from that label). In the drive, emails are stored as pdf files with original formating in tact. Attachments are also archived.

[Google script to copy gmail emails to google drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aize8AsQfYPJdDhjQVhqZjZObE4zRm93TnRmRmlMR3c&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Just announced:

Bringing it all together: [15 GB now shared between Drive, Gmail, and Google+ Photos](http://readwrite.com/2013/05/13/google-combines-storage-across-all-its-apps-15gb-total)

With this new combined storage space, you won’t have to worry about how much you’re storing and where. For example, maybe you’re a heavy Gmail user but light on photos, or perhaps you were bumping up against your Drive storage limit but were only using 2 GB in Gmail. Now it doesn’t matter, because you can use your storage the way you want.

So, it looks like you only need to wait until they roll this out to you, which will probably be within the next few weeks.

Answer (score -2):

Gmail IMAP + Drive SDK + 30 lines of your favorite scripting language.

Use IMAP with Gmail to download the emails you want. Then use the Drive SDK to upload them to Drive (this will require programming).

Comment: Care to elaborate, please? The way it is now, it‘s not very helpful.

Comment: Use IMAP with GMail to download the emails you want. Then use the Drive SDK to upload them to Drive. This will require programming. My pleasure :) (sorry, not going to write the code for you)

Comment: The scope of the whole SE network is to help others. By giving truncated answers you are not helping anybody.

Comment: So downvote it if that's how you feel, but it is the best answer here. The fact that it is the downvoted one reflects more poorly on the SE mentality, in my opinion. Someone innocently reaching this page might think it is not the best answer, and that clearly detracts from the site.