# Can I file my emails in Google Drive folders?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I move/copy emails from Gmail to Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26755/can-i-move-copy-emails-from-gmail-to-google-docs)

I get a lot of emails related to documents I keep in google drive. I'd like to transfer my emails from gmail into the relevant google drive folders. Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is [Chrome plugin that saves your attachments to Google drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-attachments-to-driv/epoohehjbaenldfbahgcegdmlogakgin).  And [here you can find how to save your messages to Google Drive](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57403753-285/save-gmail-messages-in-google-docs/).

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not have it converted to a document if that's possible.